# In node.js, how do I read the background colour attribute of the DOM body?

Tags: javascript, dom, popup, document-body

When a popup pops up, I change the background colour of the parent page to dark grey:

```
 document.body.style.backgroundColor = "darkGray";
```

When the modal is closed, I need the page to return to its original colour. To do that, I need to get that attribute before the modal is called. Any ideas?

Comment: unclear what nodejs has to do with reading DOM.

Comment: You're doing it the wrong way, if you have to remember what it was before. Just add a class to it, and remove it later

Comment: So store the value in a variable before you replace it. OR use a class and toggle the class.

Comment: Some good points here. It's not node that's going to be reading the attribute, but it's node that's driving the process.

I could add and remove a class - and I might do that - but the framework I'm using makes that less than straight forward, so I'd rather avoid it.

Storing the value in a variable is my preferred option. The question is: how do I get that variable in the first place?